# Icons not displaying properly on Firefox

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, retina-display

I'm using the glyphicons pro library for my website and I noticed that on my MBP Retina, they show up as hi-res on Chrome, but not FF (even though FF says it's up-to-date). Here are a couple of screenshots (first one is FF):

[image: Firefox 23.0]

[image: Chrome 27.0.1453.116]

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are these `img` or `background-image`?  Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be using a Web accelerator addon in Firefox that could cause this pixelation. Try disabling that plugin and see if it works.

If thats not the case then your Firefox may be running in 256 color mode, for details see [Website colors are wrong.](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Website%20colors%20are%20wrong)

Another possibility - check the properties of the shortcut you use to load Firefox (right-click, then Properties). Under the Compatibility tab, make sure nothing is selected.

or Maybe your screen res changes in FireFox, see [this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Screen_resolution_changes_when_launching_application)